# how to use terraformer to update the existing statefile incrementally

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template, azure-rm

We are using Azure cloud platform and used Terraform to provision our resources using Azuredevops pipelines. So when we provisioned the resources we kept the statefiles resource wise(eg:ApIM, Appservice, AKS, Storage Accounts, etc..) and the statefiles where in sync with the actual resource.
But we have other ADO pipelines as part of our application releases, which are making some changes on the previous terraform built resources like (API creation and update, Tags update to resources, additional component creation to the base resource etc..). So those changes made our terraform states out of sync the actual resources and when we triggered the pipeline for terraform plan  for those resources, number of changes are showing and some resources are showing to replace itself.

So, We need to make our existing resources statefile in sync with any kind of pipeline\manual changes from the portal and we have to follow the practice of incrementally updating the statefile.

So by searching in internet we found that we can achieve this using terraformer and planning to add a Pipeline for terraformer task that will update  those changes to the existing statefiles for each resource (planning to schedule this pipeline weekly).

Is it possible to use terrafomer to make the incremental changes with both statefile and already used terraform manifests in sync.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your using of Terraform for IaaC seems wrong. If you plan to deploy resources through terraform then those resources should not be modified by other external factors. If it does, then you lose one of terraform's key feature i.e, maintaining a state and updating the resources.
2. Terraformer is a completely different tool that is not suited for your direct usecase. It is used to generate tf files/state files for existing resources created via methods other than terraform (Eg: console)

My recommendation for you will be to go through the basics of terraform, Iaac and restructure your pipelines/architecture.

Below are some links that were helpful for me.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state

https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/examples

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules